# Granting the "Debug Apex" permission for the Apex Debugger as an ISV Partner

Tags: apex, ide, debugging, isv, lma

I'm following the instructions under [Get Started with the Apex Debugger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_perm_set.htm). I'm up to the point where I create a Permission Set for the debugger user to enable the **"Debug Apex"** permission under System Permissions. Except I can't see that permission.

Do I need to do something else to access it?

Without it the Force.com IDE fails with the following error. (Which I assume is directly related to the permission I can't set)

> Your user doesn't have the permission to debug Apex.

I've tried to configure this permission from both a LMA login and direct login as the System Administrator in the sandbox.

The **Start Partner Debugging Session** button does appear in the Apex debugger setup page. It generates a `forceide:` link with a valid session ID.

---

There isn't much to go on in the Force.com IDE Log Viewer. There is a message:

> (DebuggerConnectionException) nnot connect to the remote server (Open log file for full message and/or stacktrace).

This entry doesn't appear in the force-ide.log file.

---

Note that this corresponds to the [Debug Apex Code in Subscriber Orgs](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_apex_debugger.htm) Spring '17 feature.

Answer (score 3):

The required permission isn't called "Debug Apex" as it currently appears in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_perm_set.htm). Rather it is

> **Permission Name:** View and Debug Managed Apex
>   **Description:** View the Apex code in your packages, and debug code with Apex Debugger, when logged in to subscriber orgs. Limited to code in Managed - Released packages.

This permission should be assigned to the user in the LMA org rather than the subscriber org.