# Unable to set breakpoints in Apex Debugger when using ISV Partner login

Tags: apex, debugging, isv, apex-debugger

I'm working through the steps from [Get Started with the ISV Customer Debugger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_isv_getstart.htm) and trying to get the Apex Debugger to set breakpoints for code from the managed package.

I've logged into the subscriber org from the LMA app where the originating user has the ["View and Debug Managed Apex" system permission](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/173294/102).

[image]
Dragging the debugging session details into Eclipse appears to have worked. 
It's worth observing that this process was extremely slow and it appears to lockup the originating browser processes while attempts are made to pull down all the orgs metadata. But it did eventually finish.

In Eclipse I went through the steps to [Set Up a Debug Configuration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_isv_setup_debug_config.htm). Again, this appeared to work as I got what appears to be a debugging session.

[image]

[image]

However, any attempt to set an actual breakpoint in Eclipse fails as the options are disabled.

Trying "Enable/Disable Breakpoint" results in an Information message.

[image: Breakpoint options]

> The chosen operation is not enabled

[image: The chosen operation is not enabled]

After which that option is grayed out.

[image]

Playing with the Tooling API I can see ApexDebuggerSession records with the Status of Active.

**How do I get a breakpoint on Apex from my managed package?**

---

I'm using:

- v4.6.3 of the Eclipse IDE
- v38.0.0.20170110588 of the Force.com IDE Debugger plugin
- v38.0.0.201701101558 of the Force.com IDE plugin

I've also got v39.6.0.v20170406-0039 of the Force.com IDE (Pilot) plugin

Comment: Is there something showing up in the Eclipse .log file?

Comment: @Gunnar I was monitoring `...\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.salesforce.ide.core\force-ide.log`. There were a number of Metadata API errors prior to trying to create the breakpoint. All around trying to pull details from packages that belong to other parties. There was nothing when trying to create the breakpoint. Do I need to adjust the logging level?

Comment: Can you please check the ...\workspace\.metadata\.log file for any output? I just want to make sure that you don't run into the Neon.3 Equinox resolver issue (https://bugs.eclipse.org/514149).

Comment: Also, I see that you have the Pilot plug-in. Did you install both into the same Eclipse version?

Comment: @Gunnar I've got both the pilot plugin and normal plugin installed in the same version. I'll try removing the pilot plugin then check the output in the log you mentioned.

Comment: @Gunnar Uninstalling the "Force.com IDE (Pilot) plugin" seemed to resolve the issue. I can not toggle and hit breakpoints. Do you want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Gunnar As a note, it took me 20+ minutes to get the debugger running as it attempts to pull down all metadata in the org. For everything outside my package it fails with a `Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: Foo__c` message. During that time it also locks up *all* my Chrome tabs/processes.

Comment: Chrome tabs? That's weird.

Comment: @Gunnar The lockup happens when I drag the Session details from a Chrome tab into Eclipse. It completely locks up Eclipse and **all** Chrome processes for about 10 minutes. The target subscriber org has a number of managed packages installed. I suspect it is trying and failing to pull all the metadata down. Lots of errors in the log.

Comment: The blocking of the Eclipse UI sounds like a bug. Such extensive work should run in the background not blocking the Eclipse UI. However, I'm puzzled by the interaction with Chrome. I wouldn't expect Chrome to lock up as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message "The chosen operation is not enabled." usually comes up when there is something broken in an Eclipse installation. There are multiple ways to debug this. For example, one way is to go the the host OSGi console and look at the installed bundles/plug-ins. Anything in state "INSTALLED" indicates an issue.

Another option is to look at the Eclipse log file (in `.metadata/.log`) or the Eclipse Error Log view. It logs resolution errors during startup.

As a note, you should not run both plug-ins (Force.com IDE plugin "classic" and the Salesforce DX version "Force.com IDE (Pilot)") in the same Eclipse instance. There will be dependency issues.

Comment: I removed the "Force.com IDE (Pilot)" plugin. That change alone appeared to be enough to get the debugger going as I could toggle the break points and then hit them and step through the code. Thanks for your help.